# How to Implement shake gestures in an Apple Watch application?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

The [WatchKit reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WatchKit_framework/) seems to make no mention about it. Have I missed something? Or is it really not possible to implement a shake gesture in an Apple Watch application?

The following is a typical example of a shake gesture implementation on iOS:

```
// MARK: Gestures
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if(event.subtype == UIEventSubtype.MotionShake) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use coreMotion to get movement.
I build this [simple wrapper](https://github.com/ezefranca/WatchShaker) on my Github.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to do anything having to do with `UIEvent`s in WatchKit right now, with the current solution's "remoted UI" approach where you mostly just get to tell the watch how to use the pre-arranged UI from the storyboard and react to actions like tapping a button or a table row. There will be support for a lot more code running on the watch later this year, according to Apple.

Update: Native apps are now possible for watchOS 2. This functionality may be present.

Comment: At WWDC they announced this is now possible in the Watch OS 2 beta.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible in Watch OS2 with CMMotionManager a part of CoreMotion.

You can have this workaround.

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable) {
   let handler:CMAccelerometerHandler = {(data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

       if (data!.acceleration.z > 0) {
          // User did shake
       }
   }
   motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: handler)
}
```

Comment: I am seeing a constant of 0 in here to detect shaking. Is this number appropriate for real-world use?

Comment: @FullDecent yes it works in my project, since acceleration.z return (-)value when watch is in normal positions, when you do the shake motion  acceleration.z return (+)value or greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

How Roger say, an workaround is use the CoreMotion.

You can use coreMotion to get movement.
I build this [simple wrapper](https://github.com/ezefranca/WatchShaker) on my Github.